# Creating a new dekstop using the Win32 API in Windows 8

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to write an application which will creates a new desktop using the Win32 API.

The below code works in Windows 7 but but in Windows 8 the desktop is created with out the desktop icons and with an empty taskbar.

```
public class Desktop
{
    private const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020;

    private const long DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK = 0x0001L;

    private const uint DELETE = 0x00010000;
    private const uint READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000;
    private const uint WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000;
    private const uint WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000;

    private const uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = DELETE | READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC | WRITE_OWNER;

    private const long DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002L;
    private const long DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040L;
    private const long DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080L;
    private const long DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100L;
    private const long DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004L;
    private const long DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008L;
    private const long DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001L;
    private const long DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010L;
    private const long DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020L;
    private const uint AccessRights = (uint)DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD |
        (uint)DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK |
        (uint)DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW |
        (uint)DESKTOP_ENUMERATE |
        (uint)DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS |
        (uint)DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP |
        (uint)DESKTOP_CREATEMENU |
        (uint)DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL |
        (uint)DESKTOP_READOBJECTS |
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED;

    private delegate bool EnumDesktopProc(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcessWindowStation();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumDesktops(IntPtr hwinsta, EnumDesktopProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string desktopName, string device, string deviceMode, int flags, uint accessMask, [In] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attributes);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenDesktop(string lpszDesktop, uint dwFlags, bool fInherit, uint dwDesiredAccess);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, ref PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public int dwX;
        public int dwY;
        public int dwXSize;
        public int dwYSize;
        public int dwXCountChars;
        public int dwYCountChars;
        public int dwFillAttribute;
        public int dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    private static List<string> _desktops = new List<string>();

    public static IntPtr Create(string name)
    {
        var securityAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        securityAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(securityAttributes);

        return CreateDesktop(name, null, null, (int) DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, AccessRights, ref securityAttributes);
    }

    public static IntPtr Open(string name)
    {
        return OpenDesktop(name, 0, false, AccessRights);
    }

    public static bool Show(IntPtr desktopPrt)
    {
        if (desktopPrt == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
        return SwitchDesktop(desktopPrt);
    }

    public static void Prepare(string desktopName)
    {
        CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", desktopName);
    }

    public static bool Exists(string name)
    {
        return GetDesktops().Any(s => s == name);
    }

    private static void CreateProcess(string path, string desktopName)
    {
        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.lpDesktop = desktopName;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

        var lpCurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        CreateProcess(path, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, IntPtr.Zero, lpCurrentDirectory, ref si, ref pi);
    }

    private static string[] GetDesktops()
    {
        IntPtr windowStation = GetProcessWindowStation();
        if (windowStation == IntPtr.Zero) return new string[0];

        _desktops.Clear();

        bool result = EnumDesktops(windowStation, DesktopEnumProc, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (!result) return new string[0];

        return _desktops.ToArray();
    }

    private static bool DesktopEnumProc(string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        _desktops.Add(lpszDesktop);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var desktopName = "TestDesktop";
var desktopPrt = Desktop.Create(desktopName);
Desktop.Show(desktopPrt);
Desktop.Prepare(desktopName);
```

The Sysinternals Desktops app (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) uses the same API and it works in Windows 8 so there must be something that I am missing.

Does anyone have any pointers for me? Or does anyone know of any where I can find examples of how to use this API? MSDN for the API calls gives a lot of information but no many examples.

Thanks ;D

Comment: It can be a "SysWOW64" problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fbe1baec-821d-44c3-ac96-bc6e910790e8/createdesktop-on-windows-7-no-taskbar-an-key-combination-doesnt-work?forum=windowssdk

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Sry, I realised that you run it in your code snippet, please ignore my comment.

How about explicitly running `explorer.exe` for each desktop you create? That one handles icons, taskbar, etc ...
When you run SysInternals Desktops app you can see that it actually does that.